# How do i convert to ascii in RUST

Tags: rust, ascii

How do i convert a string, str or char to ascii

```
fn main() {
    let key:String = String::from("A");
    println!("{:?}",key.to_ascii_lowercase());
}
```

i was expecting the ascii representation of 'A' which is 65

Comment: Potentially relevant background reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and [What is a String](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html#what-is-a-string) from the rust book.

Comment: Unclear what it is you're asking.  The representation of 'A' in most code pages, including ASCII and UTF-8 (rust's internal encoding) is a code unit with the value of 65 (lowercase 'a' is code point 97). Are you looking to find the numerical values of characters within text? Or, If you're wanting to transcode from Rust's internal UTF-8 to ASCII, what are you expecting to happen for chars that are outside the range of ASCII?

Comment: I agree it's unclear what is being asked and it's old and there is no chosen answer. The question calls for a char to ascii. The code calls for a string a to ascii.

Answer (score 4):

I believe, what OP was asking, is how to get ASCII code representation of string. If it's so, then one just has to understand that `String` is just a wrapper around `Vec<u8>`, and `str` is just a fat pointer to slice of `u8`s. The key property being that `String` and `str` guarantee (under assumption that they weren't constructed using unsafe code), that underlying bytes storage contains valid utf-8 encoded sequence.

Hence it's only possible to get ASCII representation of string, if it contains only valid ASCII symbols (obviously). To do that one can just call [to_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_bytes) method, which will return reference to underlying bytes array. But again, if String/str contains anything other than ASCII, say an emoji, well then, you'll just get some utf-8 encoded byte sequence.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

`to_ascii_lowercase()` doesn't convert `String` to `char`.

If you have `char`, use `as` to convert it, for example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let key: char = 'A';
    println!("{:?}", key.to_ascii_lowercase() as u8);
}
```

And since it's lowercase now, it would produce `97` for `a` instead of `65` for `A`.

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b42a1b6d8bd2998f30b6f1ad2c109f7)

Answer (score 1):

> i was expecting the ascii representation of 'A' which is 65

Why? The documentation couldn't be clearer:

> Makes a copy of the value in its ASCII lower case equivalent.

So its purpose is to perform a lowercasing operation *in the ascii range only*, as opposed to [`char::to_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_lowercase) which performs a unicode-aware lowercasing (across the entire unicode range).

And it returns a `char`, not a `u*`.

Plus `to_ascii_lowercase` would convert `A` to `a`, so the ASCII code would be 97 not 65.

As to your issue, if you read through the documentation of `char`, tacked onto [`char::from_u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.from_u32) you'll find:

> Note that all chars are valid u32s, and can be cast to one with as:
>
> ```rust
> let c = '';
> let i = c as u32;
>
> assert_eq!(128175, i);
> ```

Unicode matches ASCII in that range, so it'll do what you want for any char < 128.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for this one?

```
let key = b"A";  // let key = "A".as_bytes();

println!("{key:?} {:?}", key.to_ascii_lowercase());
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e3935557ce52e345a36bf427cd10d4b)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Vec::from()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/alloc/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-From%3C%26str%3E-for-Vec%3Cu8%3E) to convert the given [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/alloc/string/struct.String.html) to a vector [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/alloc/vec/struct.Vec.html) that holds values of type [`u8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/primitive.u8.html) were `u8` is the ascii value of the character in `String`.

```rust
Vec::from("A") // [65]
Vec::from("ab".to_string()) // [97, 98]
```

Comment: You do not need to allocate to see if it's representable in ASCII range.